# Unexpected token, expected,

Tags: react-native

creating a shopping list application with the React-Native framework. This piece of code keeps throwing an exception 'unexpected token, expected,' on line 29 (rowHasChanged...) however I have no idea what it is talking about:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1! !== row2
  })
  };
 }
```

What I'm I missing?

Thanks

Comment: change (row1, row2) => row1! !== row2 to: (row1, row2) => !row1 !== row2

Comment: I think it should be (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2